# Generate random list of values with certain percentage of occurences of each value in python

Tags: python, random

I'm looking to generate a list of size N, let's say, where I have m unique elements {v<sub>1</sub>,v<sub>2</sub>,...,v<sub>m</sub>} and I can be certain that there are exactly Np<sub>1</sub> occurances of v<sub>1</sub>, Np<sub>2</sub> occurances of v<sub>2</sub>, ... , Np<sub>m</sub> occurances of v<sub>m</sub>, where p<sub>1</sub> + p<sub>2</sub> + ... + p<sub>3</sub> = 1.

As a specific example, I'd like to generate a random 10 element list of 1,2,and 3 where 1 occurs 20% of the time, 2 occurs 30% of the time, and 3 occurs 50% of the time the following lists would be acceptable randomly generated lists:

```
L1 = [1,3,2,1,3,3,3,2,3,2]
L2 = [3,3,3,1,2,1,3,3,2,2]
```

I'm looking for the most general, pythonic way to achieve this if my input is a list of tuples with (value,probability) pairs and N, the length of the list to be generated.
e.g. for the above case:

```
T = [(1,0.2),(2,0.3),(3,0.5)]
N = 10
```

Comment: Then presumably you want to specify the inputs in terms of Np1, etc, rather than fractions which may be inexact for a given N

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Compute the quantities you need of each element.
Create a list with all of the elements you need.
Shuffle the list.  For instance:

```
>>> deck = [1]*2 + [2]*3 + [3]*5
>>> deck
[1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3]
>>> random.shuffle(deck)
>>> deck
[1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 3, 2]
```

Combining this with a creation sequence ...

```
import random

T = [(1,0.2),(2,0.3),(3,0.5)]
N = 10
deck = []

for item in T:
    deck += [item[0]] * int(round(N*item[1]))
print deck
random.shuffle(deck)
print deck
```

Output:

```
[1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3]
[1, 3, 3, 3, 2, 3, 1, 3, 2, 2]
```

---

PATCH

To guarantee that the list is of the proper length, we can take a low-thought way out: generate all but the last item, and then fill out the rest of the list with that last one.  The solution **TemporalWolf** proposed is better overall, but this one works for most applications.

```
for item in T[:-1]:
    deck += [item[0]] * int(round(N*item[1]))
# Use final item to guarantee that the list is the correct length
deck += [T[-1][0]] * (N - len(deck))
```

We will still have trouble if N is too low, and many of the frequencies round the repetition to 0.  This can also fail if the last item has a low frequency, and other items round up a lot: if the list is already too long, this will fail.

Comment: It's worth mentioning: both our solutions do not produce the expected results if the probabilities do not produce whole numbers via `prob * num`

Comment: Right.  I used **round** to reduce that problem, but larger groups can still hit that case.

Comment: Any grouping that results in a 50/50 will produce an extra term, as `round()` will make any `x.5` into `x+1`: `[(1,0.45),(2,0.55)]` will produce eleven terms. I was the first to upvote your answer, I'm just worried future visitors may not intuit that.

Answer (score 0):

build the list, then use `random.shuffle()` to make it random. An example:

```
import random

def build_list(params, num):
    result = []
    for value, prob in params:
        count = int(prob * num)
        for _ in range(count):
            result.append(value)
    random.shuffle(result)
    return result
```

or, as a list comprehension:

```
def build_list(params, num):
    result = [value for value, prob in params for _ in range(int(prob * num))]
    random.shuffle(result)
    return result
```

result:

```
>>> build_list([(1,0.2),(2,0.3),(3,0.5)], 10)
[3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 1, 3, 3, 2, 1]
```

**Note**: Because you're specifying probabilities, this will produce **at most** `prob * num` results... because if that is not an integer it drops the fraction:

```
>>> build_list([(1,0.2),(2,0.25),(3,0.55)], 10)
[3, 3, 2, 2, 3, 1, 1, 3, 3]
```

the lost term has a 50% chance of being `2` or `3`. So there is that caveat.

To account for this loss, you have to either pick:

1. The biggest probability gets the extra value (and figure out a tie breaker)
2. Randomly choose which by calculating the weight

An example which adds missing terms randomly weighted:

```
def build_list(params, num):
    result = [value for value, prob in params for _ in range(int(prob * num))]
    while len(result) < num:  # some value lost 
        roll = random.random()  # pick which value
        prob_sum = 0
        for value, prob in params:
            prob_sum += (prob * num) % 1
            if prob_sum > roll:
                result.append(value)
                break
    random.shuffle(result)
    return result
```